# Rename file containing '©' character

Tags: encoding, decode, utf

We received as input in our application (running on Windows) a list of files. These files were automatically extracted from a database with a script.

Apparently some of the names are containing special characters (like accents) and these characters are rendered as '©' on our side.

How can rename programmatically these text files (around 900'000) to get rid of this character?
We cannot change the source neither re-extract the files. 
The problem is that because of this character another program involved with our system does not accept the files.

Comment: Does it have to be programmatically? There are many utilities on the market that can batch-rename: http://www.techsupportalert.com/best-free-rename-utility.htm#Quick_Selection_Guide

Comment: It can also not be programmatically, but I have to remove that special character from all the files in once. there are around 5o different folders. But if that application can run recursively then looks very interesting!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up creating a new script that reads the input files and search for special characters in their title.

It was quite easy indeed:

```
string filename = filename.Replace("©", "e");
```

Since the '©' is in the filename, the script (in C#) is able to recognize it and replace the match accordingly. In this way I can loop through all the folders and subfolders simply reading the filename and change specials characters.

Thank you all for the contributions!

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the unix command `rename`. It allows you to apply a perl regex to the names of a bunch of files. In this case you might want something like:

```
$ rename 's/[^a-zA-Z0-9]//' *
```

In debian the `rename` command is part of the `perl` package. It should also be available on CPAN.

Comment: Stupid me... Well, rename might be part of some windows perl distribution too :)